# Did the Others come back with the magic?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the series, we see magic starts to come back with the birth of the dragons. We also see a resurgence of the Others as the series moves on.

Is there any correlation between these two events? Are the Others mystical creatures that exist only when magic does or have they just been amassing their strength until now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The shortest answer in both the books and TV series is "we don't know yet".

We do not know yet what the origin of the Others is. Some characters speculate that they appear in the coldest winters, and they seem to be related to ice and cold (probably the "Ice" part of the "Song of Ice and Fire" theme). They might or might not be related to the resurgence of magic in the world, but we at least know they predate the birth of the dragons, because we're shown an encounter with the Others in the prologue, before Daenerys' eggs hatch. I mention this because, in turn, some characters (e.g. the warlocks of Qarth) believe the return of the *dragons* brought magic to the world, but since we know the Others predate Dany's dragons, they must have been brought by a different kind of magic, if any.

Comment: Also, Craster has been dealing with them for quite some time. So they have never been really *gone*.

Comment: You bring up good point that I completely forgot about, the prelude included them prior to the dragons.

Comment: @SystemDown I know Craster was dealing with the wildlings, but with the Others?!?

Comment: @major-mann Craster's dealings with the Others are explicitly shown in the TV show, and mentioned in the books. He is a "godly man" who "sacrifices" his sons to the "cold gods", as more or less explained by him and his daughter/wives.

Comment: @AndresF cool... Thanks... In my mind I had seen it as him sacrificing to the tree, I am definitely going to read over that again!

Comment: @major-mann: I think the book is deliberately written so that it could be interpreted either way, so that people will at first think trees, and only much later realize the truth.